# Cannot globally hijack/replace Node's require

Tags: javascript, node.js

How do you globally hijack/replace Node's require? Here is a dummy example I made with two files:

```
// index.js
global.require = function hijacked() {
    console.log('not gonna call anything');
}
require('./file');

// file.js
console.log('in file');
console.log('require name: ', require.name);
console.log('global.require name', global.require.name);
```

Then running `node index.js`, I was expecting to just see `not gonna call anything`, but instead I only saw

```
in file
require name: require
global.require name: hijacked
```

So this is NOT replacing `require`, merely creating a new function on the global scope.

Next I tried this:

```
// index.js
const original = require;
require = function hijacked(arg) {
   console.log('hijacking');
   original(arg);
}
require('./file');

// file.js
console.log('in file');
console.log('require name: ', require.name);
```

This time, I saw

```
hijacking
in file2
require name:  require
```

Again, `require`'s replacement is not persisted between files. So how can I do this?

Comment: Perhaps, [require-hook](https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-hook)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each module gets its `require` from `Module.prototype`. [Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).

So you could do something like this to replace original

```
// index.js
const Module = require('module')

const {require: oldRequire} = Module.prototype

Module.prototype.require = function hijacked(file) {
  console.log('hijacked> ', file )

  return oldRequire.apply(this, arguments)
}

require('./file1')
```

In file1

```
require('path')

console.log('in file 1')
```

Output

```
$ node .
hijacked>  ./file1
hijacked>  path
in file 1
```